# Electrical energy in a fighter aircraft

Tags: energy

A car uses a car battery and an alternator powered by the engine.  But where does the electrical energy for fighter aircraft comes from to maintain the onboard systems?
And which voltage and frequency do they use?

EDIT:
and how does a fighter aircraft alternator works on a jet engine, what causes the spin at the alternator?

Comment: This question is not about electronic design and should probably be in another Stack.

Comment: I don't think there's a Fighter Jet StackExchange yet. Over to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) to suggest it! :)

Comment: @JYelton  There is [Aviation.SE](http://aviation.stackexchange.com) ([please don't cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu), though).  Having said that, I think that this question is more a less on-topic here on EE.SE .

Comment: While there are indeed similarities to an automotive system, one key conceptual difference is that many jet aircraft have a "Ram Air Turbine" - effectively a "windmill" which can fold out and provide emergency power for electronics and hydraulics in the event of the failure of all engine(s).

Answer (score 12):

It's conceptually similar to an automotive electrical system. There is a generator (driven by the engine), batteries and some other stuff.

Small planes tend to use 28VDC for the power bus, which is just double the voltage used in an automotive electrical system (voltage is quoted with the fan up front running, since there will be bigger problems should it stop- automotive systems are about 14V with the motor running).

Some mid-size commercial planes that I'm familiar with have both 28VDC and "wild frequency" 120VAC which can be used for internal lighting and such like. The latter has a frequency that varies with engine speed but it's usually over 400Hz. High frequency is used to keep the weight of transformers and motors down, while still being low enough that conventional materials can be used. The use of 400Hz nominal in aircraft dates back to before WWII and the use of gyroscopes and such like.

Military fighter jets have high power requirements for their size (eg. the F16 has a 40/60kVA generator driven by a hydraulic constant speed drive from the engine). Because of the high power consumption, higher voltages than 28V are used - 120/208 400Hz 3-phase- to keep the weight of wires down. The 1970-era F16 is a fly-by-wire so there is also a backup generator and multiple batteries. The 3-phase AC can be easily converted to 28VDC using a transformer-rectifier unit (TRU).

You can find much more in this [Naval Technician training manual](http://www.hnsa.org/doc/pdf/aviationpower.pdf).

Comment: Spehro you continue to amaze. Nice answer.

Comment: Yes, when aircraft say "28 VDC" they *actually* mean alternator float voltage, so they're really talking about what the rest of us call 24 VDC.  Whereas all our cars use a 12 VDC battery, an aviation mechanic's car uses a 14V battery :)

Answer (score 3):

They have alternators and batteries also. The most common specification (in my experience) is MIL-STD-704, and there are several variations in this standard. The most common (again in my experience) used is DC 28V. The spec covers many aspects of the rail (usually at how unreliable it is), one of which is cranking and battery supply.

Batteries provide about ~20V from memory, and when engines are starting up the voltage drops way down like in car ignition (presumably to spin the turbines, something like turning a car engine over). After this, the alternators take over and provide nominal 28V.

There are other specs of power (AC) as well, which I would imagine are used when there is a bigger power draw (large military aicraft?)

EDIT: Variants are:

- AC 115V RMS, 400Hz
- AC 115V RMS, 360-800Hz Variable
- AC 115V RMS, 60Hz 3 phase
- DC 28V
- DC 270V

Ref link http://www.everyspec.com/MIL-STD/MIL-STD-0700-0799/MIL-STD-704F_1083/

Answer (score 0):

This is a generalized response, as there are numerous exceptions in various aircraft.

For in flight power, most fighter aircraft rely on a generator which can also double as a starter (not on all aircraft).  The generator is DC output (often 28V) and usually 200 to 400 amp, and runs off an accessory drive on the engine turbine.

Traditionally avionics run off 28VDC and 200V 400Hz.  400Hz alternators (but termed generators) are used for higher power requirements of many aircraft, and are supplied by GPU (ground power units).

The tendency is to use 400Hz power at higher voltages to minimize the size of wire required to distribute power.  In a general sense, while most avionics is 400Hz powered, there are often versions which are 28VDC powered for specific needs.

Other power including 50/60Hz may also be employed in some aircraft, but usually not fighters.

While primary and starting power may be 28VDC, aircraft with higher power requirements (eg jammers) may use 270VDC and 400VDC genreators.  AC power is made with inverters (often termed converters).  AC power is also made with alternators (termed generators), and is nominally 400 Hz.

28VDC starter generators are more common where an aircraft is intended to be operated off a unimproved field.

Frequently, the 28VDC system uses a starter/generator (DC) to start an APU (auxiliary power unit) which is sometimes called a SPU (starter power unit).  Bleed air or electrical power is then used to start the main power plants.

Also, there is a long history in fighter aircraft of having generators / alternators which are hydraulically powered.  I am not clear on the reasoning, except perhaps packaging, as it is certainly not more efficient.

If an aircraft has a jammer, requiring high power, there may be an alternator specific to that device.

On most aircraft the electrical system is tailored to the specific mission and the equipment needed for that mission.  Due to avionics having reduced power requirements (vs traditional power needs) there is a trend to low voltage DC.  Many guns also run on low voltage 28VDC.  However aircraft power systems are a mix of what was once in place and the emerging needs.  Many fighter aircraft have multiple busses.  Often a primary and secondary DC bus and one or more AC busses.  So there is no hard and fast, nor typical.  And some of the legacy fighters like the F-104 had multiple "generators" (really alternators) some of which were hydraulically powered from one of the engine hydraulic pumps.

With commercial aircraft such as the 787 being almost exclusively electrically powered, for example, using electric pumps, rather than turbine bleed air for cabin pressurization, the same trend can be expected in fighter aircraft particularly where it enhances survivability and readiness.